# Cell model output not showing up

Tags: java, oop, multidimensional-array, output

So I am working on an extremely basic, Object-oriented model of cellular growth in Java. Below is my Cell class, which compiles fine with no errors.

```
package cancerModel;
public class Cell {

public int x; //x position of cell
public int y; //y position of cell
public char type; //type of cell


public Cell(int x, int y, char type)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.type = type;
}

public void addCellToGrid(char[][] grid, int x, int y, char type)
{
    grid[x][y] = type;
}


public boolean checkAnySpace4(char[][] grid, int x, int y)
{
    if(grid[x-1][y] == 'N' || grid[x-1][y] == 'M'|| grid[x-1][y] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x-1][y-1] == 'N' || grid[x-1][y-1] == 'M'|| grid[x][y-1] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x][y-1] == 'N' || grid[x][y-1] == 'M'|| grid[x][y-1] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x+1][y] == 'N' || grid[x+1][y] == 'M'|| grid[x+1][y] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
        return true;
}


public boolean checkAnySpace8(char[][] grid, int x, int y)
{
    if(grid[x-1][y] == 'N' || grid[x-1][y] == 'M'|| grid[x-1][y] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x-1][y-1] == 'N' || grid[x-1][y-1] == 'M'|| grid[x-1][y-1] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x][y-1] == 'N' || grid[x][y-1] == 'M'|| grid[x][y-1] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x+1][y] == 'N' || grid[x+1][y] == 'M'|| grid[x+1][y] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x][y+1] == 'N' || grid[x][y+1] == 'M'|| grid[x][y+1] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x+1][y+1] == 'N' || grid[x+1][y+1] == 'M'|| grid[x+1][y+1] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x+1][y-1] == 'N' || grid[x+1][y-1] == 'M'|| grid[x+1][y-1] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(grid[x-1][y+1] == 'N' || grid[x-1][y+1] == 'M'|| grid[x-1][y+1] == 'C')
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
        return true;
}
public void divide(char[][] grid, char type, int x, int y)
{
    if(type == 'N')
    {
        grid[x-1][y] = 'N';
        grid[x][y-1] = 'N';
        grid[x-1][y-1] = 'N';
        grid[x+1][y] = 'N';
    }
     if (type == 'M')
    {
        grid[x-1][y] = 'M';
        grid[x][y-1] = 'M';
        grid[x-1][y-1] = 'M';
        grid[x+1][y] = 'M';
    }
    if(type =='C')
    {
        grid[x-1][y] = 'C';
        grid[x][y-1] = 'C';
        grid[x-1][y-1] = 'C';
        grid[x+1][y] = 'C';
        grid[x][y+1] = 'C';
        grid[x+1][y+1] = 'C';
        grid[x+1][y-1] = 'C';
        grid[x-1][y+1] = 'C';   
    }   
}
public void die(char[][] grid, int x, int y)
{
    grid[x][y] = ' ';
}   

public void mutate(char[][] grid,char type, int x, int y)
{
    if(type == 'N')
    {
        grid[x][y] = 'M';
    }
    else if (type == 'M')
    {
        grid[x][y] = 'C';
    }
 }
}
```

Next, I have another class called Setup which is suppose to initialize the model. The start() function is meant to hold the logic for the progression of the model, but it is not fully implemented yet. At this point, I'm simply trying to make sure I'll be able to view the grid, so I make 10 Cells and place them at random points in the grid.

```
package cancerModel;
public class Setup {

public double m = .05; //mutation rate
public double e = .6 ; //survival rate (1 - e = death rate)
public double p_c = .7; //growth rate for cancerous cells
public double p_n = .8; //growth rate for normal/mutated cells




public void printGrid(char[][] grid)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

public void start(int steps)
{
    char[][] grid = new char[50][50];
    int random = (int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
    int random2 = (int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
    for(int i = 1; i < steps; i++)
    {
        Cell cell = new Cell(random,random2,'N');
        cell.addCellToGrid(grid, random, random2, cell.type);
    }
printGrid(grid);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Setup e = new Setup();
    e.start(10);
}

}
```

When I run this though, I am getting no character output whatsoever. My assumption is that it is just printing an empty 50x50 array. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Is there something wrong in how I'm creating the Cells and adding them to the grid, or is it a problem in how I am printing the grid? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your problem and question, you need the following modification to populate the 50 x 50 array:

1. Move the random and random2 statements inside the for loop
2. Change your random from `50 + 1` to `49 + 1` or instead the size of your array to `51 x 51`

**Issue 1**, the reason you have to shift your random statements inside the for loop is to allow generation of random place for the 10 cells that you claim. Being outside for loop means, you override the previous cell as a result your 2D array will have only one element because you keep adding the cell in the same location of the grid.

```
//move the random and random1 inside for loop for random cell positions
for (int i = 1; i < steps; i++) {
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
    int random2 = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);

    Cell cell = new Cell(random, random2, 'N');
    cell.addCellToGrid(grid, random, random2, cell.type);
}
```

**Issue 2** causes the vulnerability to have a number 50 and if you try to access the grid array with that number, you are guaranteed to get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` hence, the issue.

```
int random = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
int random2 = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);

//this can cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, either change to above or 
//modify the dimension of your grid array
int random2 = (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1);
```

Did you know about [Arrays.deepToString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))? Maybe not, you can use that to print your 2D array rather than having two for loops as shown below:

```
Arrays.deepToString(grid);
```

If you make above changes, then running your program. You are guaranteed to have 10 cells in 10 random positions of the grid array.

I added another method, to print only valid location of cell and after running the code, I get the following result:

```
grid[9][12]
grid[10][26]
grid[16][17]
grid[19][17]
grid[26][34]
grid[27][13]
grid[39][18]
grid[46][41]
grid[49][22]
```

Last but not least, I am curious what happens when your random number generator return a location that already has cell. You will overwrite that cell. I think you need a check to make sure that the generated `random` and `random1` in `grid` array does not already have cell inside it. If there is a valid Cell in that location then you need to generate another location else, store the cell in the location. I will leave that for you to handle.

To print each row in a single line, you can change your print method to have a single loop and then print grid[i] where i is the loop counter from 0 to less than 50. See below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grid[i]));
 }
```

Each grid[i] is a row of columns. We use println() to print each row in a new line.

Comment: Thank you @Raf ! this was extremely helpful.

Comment: When the array prints to the console, I am seeing it in the form, 
   [, , , , , ,], [, , , , , , ,], [, , , ,N, , ,] 

and so on. How would I get it to print row by row instead of all on a single row?

Comment: @KyleWeise updated the answer to include line that prints array in rows/column format. You are welcome btw.